# Debian 10. Intel wifi module stopped working

Tags: debian, wifi, intel

It's debian 10 with linux kernel 5.2 from backports and integrated wifi module by intel. Screenfetch (no logo):

```
tr@computer
OS: Debian 10 buster
Kernel: x86_64 Linux 5.2.0-0.bpo.2-amd64
Uptime: 4m
Packages: 2778
Shell: bash
Resolution: 1920x1080
DE: KDE 5.54.0 / Plasma 5.14.5
WM: KWin
WM Theme: Inspiration
GTK Theme: Breeze [GTK2/3]
Icon Theme: breeze
Font: Noto Sans Regular
CPU: Intel Core i5-8265U @ 8x 3.9GHz [38.0°C]
GPU: Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics (Whiskey Lake 3x8 GT2)
RAM: 1881MiB / 15995MiB
```

One day wifi just gone. No choice of wifi network in network manager GUI. Then I tried other distro (Kali Linux) and wifi worked. After reboot in debian it worked for a short period of time. Then it gone. Please tell what can I do to fix it or to tell that there is some hardware problem.

```
$ sudo ifconfig
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 186  bytes 9824 (9.5 KiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 186  bytes 9824 (9.5 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

And some dmesg:

```
$ sudo modprobe iwlwifi && sudo dmesg|grep iwl
[    7.912510] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    7.938112] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-46.ucode (-2)
[    7.939740] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-46.ucode failed with error -2
[    7.939792] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-45.ucode (-2)
[    7.940552] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-45.ucode failed with error -2
[    7.940577] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-44.ucode (-2)
[    7.941580] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-44.ucode failed with error -2
[    7.941644] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-43.ucode (-2)
[    7.942631] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-43.ucode failed with error -2
[    7.942707] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-42.ucode (-2)
[    7.943702] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-42.ucode failed with error -2
[    8.141135] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: firmware: direct-loading firmware iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-41.ucode
[    8.142804] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 41.fc1a7aea.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    9.032237] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 9462, REV=0x318
[   10.069437] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Collecting data: trigger 15 fired.
[   10.317365] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Not valid error log pointer 0x00000000 for Init uCode
[   10.317691] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Fseq Registers:
[   10.317966] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0FFC584F | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[   10.318239] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[   10.318634] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xCD9D37A4 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[   10.319179] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000A384 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[   10.319626] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x6F4F502E | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[   10.320104] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xDB70CD67 | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[   10.320462] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x42C5B8B1 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[   10.320947] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x53D8B3A8 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[   10.321331] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01000100 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[   10.321731] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[   10.322111] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[   10.322499] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[   10.322900] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: SecBoot CPU1 Status: 0x0, CPU2 Status: 0x0
[   10.323224] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to start INIT ucode: -110
[   10.323590] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Firmware not running - cannot dump error
[   10.337476] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
```

UPDATE:
Tried to update kernel and firmware:

```
sudo apt update; sudo apt -t buster-backports install linux-image-amd64 firmware-iwlwifi
```

So now:

```
Kernel: x86_64 Linux 5.10.0-0.deb10.16-amd64
```

And what gives dmesg:

```
    [    6.618473] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    6.620707] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-46.ucode (-2)
[    6.622753] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-46.ucode failed with error -2
[    6.622815] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-45.ucode (-2)
[    6.623471] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-45.ucode failed with error -2
[    6.623503] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-44.ucode (-2)
[    6.624122] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-44.ucode failed with error -2
[    6.624149] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-43.ucode (-2)
[    6.624771] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-43.ucode failed with error -2
[    6.624826] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-42.ucode (-2)
[    6.625462] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-42.ucode failed with error -2
[    6.664009] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: firmware: direct-loading firmware iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-41.ucode
[    6.666129] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 41.fc1a7aea.0 9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-41.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    6.666203] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: firmware: failed to load iwl-debug-yoyo.bin (-2)
[    7.223628] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9462, REV=0x318
[    8.249058] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: SecBoot CPU1 Status: 0x0, CPU2 Status: 0x0
[    8.251750] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Collecting data: trigger 15 fired.
[    8.497690] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Not valid error log pointer 0x00000000 for Init uCode
[    8.498219] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Fseq Registers:
[    8.498736] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0FFC584F | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[    8.499257] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[    8.499783] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xCD9D37A4 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[    8.500313] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000A384 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[    8.500875] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x6F4F502E | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[    8.501925] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xDB70CD67 | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[    8.502550] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x42C5B8B1 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[    8.503098] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x53D8B3A8 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[    8.503648] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01000100 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[    8.504235] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[    8.504881] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[    8.505848] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[    8.506416] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to start INIT ucode: -110
[    8.506984] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Collecting data: trigger 16 fired.
[    9.171407] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
[    9.184659] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: retry init count 0
[    9.185520] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9462, REV=0x318
[   10.200847] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: SecBoot CPU1 Status: 0x0, CPU2 Status: 0x0
[   10.200849] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Collecting data: trigger 15 fired.
[   10.449727] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Not valid error log pointer 0x00000000 for Init uCode
[   10.450314] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Fseq Registers:
[   10.450882] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0FFC584F | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[   10.451449] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[   10.452019] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xCD9D37A4 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[   10.452582] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000A384 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[   10.453196] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x6F4F502E | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[   10.453835] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xDB70CD67 | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[   10.454407] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x42C5B8B1 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[   10.454949] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x53D8B3A8 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[   10.455488] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01000100 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[   10.456063] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[   10.456669] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[   10.457317] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[   10.457931] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to start INIT ucode: -110
[   10.458621] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Collecting data: trigger 16 fired.
[   11.125131] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
[   11.138342] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: retry init count 1
[   11.139094] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9462, REV=0x318
[   12.152972] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: SecBoot CPU1 Status: 0x0, CPU2 Status: 0x0
[   12.155277] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Collecting data: trigger 15 fired.
[   12.401205] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Not valid error log pointer 0x00000000 for Init uCode
[   12.401772] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Fseq Registers:
[   12.402323] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0FFC584F | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[   12.402878] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[   12.403432] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xCD9D37A4 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[   12.403988] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000A384 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[   12.404542] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x6F4F502E | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[   12.405153] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xDB70CD67 | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[   12.405802] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x42C5B8B1 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[   12.406389] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x53D8B3A8 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[   12.406942] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01000100 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[   12.407529] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[   12.408148] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[   12.408739] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[   12.409355] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to start INIT ucode: -110
[   12.409953] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Collecting data: trigger 16 fired.
[   13.073281] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
[   13.086504] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: retry init count 2
```

Tried to get latest firmware from git firmware repository (see comments):

```
    [    6.826954] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    6.958153] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: firmware: direct-loading firmware iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-46.ucode
[    6.958199] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 0
[    6.958202] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 1
[    6.958205] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 2
[    6.958208] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 3
[    6.958210] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 4
[    6.958213] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 6
[    6.958216] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 8
[    6.958218] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 9
[    6.958221] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 10
[    6.958223] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 11
[    6.958226] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 15
[    6.958228] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 16
[    6.958231] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 18
[    6.958233] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 19
[    6.958236] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 20
[    6.958239] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 21
[    6.958241] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 28
[    6.959317] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 46.ea3728ee.0 9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-46.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    6.959384] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: firmware: failed to load iwl-debug-yoyo.bin (-2)
[    7.551857] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9462, REV=0x318
[    8.569650] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: SecBoot CPU1 Status: 0x0, CPU2 Status: 0x0
[    8.817784] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Not valid error log pointer 0x00000000 for Init uCode
[    8.818283] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Fseq Registers:
[    8.818773] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0FFC584F | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[    8.819268] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[    8.819767] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xCD9D37A4 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[    8.820271] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000A384 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[    8.820780] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x6F4F502E | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[    8.821366] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xDB70CD67 | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[    8.821907] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x42C5B8B1 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[    8.822452] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x53D8B3A8 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[    8.822974] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01000100 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[    8.823534] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[    8.824128] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[    8.824699] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[    8.825296] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to start INIT ucode: -110
[    8.838504] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
[    8.851562] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: retry init count 0
[    8.854369] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9462, REV=0x318
[    9.881525] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: SecBoot CPU1 Status: 0x0, CPU2 Status: 0x0
[   10.129861] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Not valid error log pointer 0x00000000 for Init uCode
[   10.130465] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Fseq Registers:
[   10.131063] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0FFC584F | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[   10.131690] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[   10.132312] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xCD9D37A4 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[   10.132925] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000A384 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[   10.133664] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x6F4F502E | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[   10.134287] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xDB70CD67 | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[   10.134884] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x42C5B8B1 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[   10.135455] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x53D8B3A8 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[   10.136016] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01000100 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[   10.136623] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[   10.137361] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[   10.137978] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[   10.138540] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to start INIT ucode: -110
[   10.151474] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
[   10.164717] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: retry init count 1
[   10.165540] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9462, REV=0x318
[   11.193707] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: SecBoot CPU1 Status: 0x0, CPU2 Status: 0x0
[   11.441253] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Not valid error log pointer 0x00000000 for Init uCode
[   11.441813] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Fseq Registers:
[   11.442349] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0FFC584F | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[   11.442890] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[   11.443431] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xCD9D37A4 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[   11.443972] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000A384 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[   11.444512] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x6F4F502E | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[   11.445052] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xDB70CD67 | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[   11.445636] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x42C5B8B1 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[   11.446288] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x53D8B3A8 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[   11.446852] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01000100 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[   11.447439] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[   11.448055] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[   11.448641] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[   11.449248] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to start INIT ucode: -110
[   11.461479] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
[   11.473425] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: retry init count 2
```

Comment: Update your system to a newer 5.10.127-2~bpo10+1 kernel and newer `iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-46.ucode` firmware: `sudo apt update; sudo apt -t buster-backports install linux-image-amd64 firmware-iwlwifi`, reboot and report back.

Comment: Successfully updated, but nothing changed. I will update original post with detail, so it is too long for comment.

Comment: You could also get the newest iwlwifi firmware from the [linux-firmware git repository](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/tree/) (here is [a direct download link](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/plain/iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-46.ucode)). Place that file into `/lib/firmware`, update your initramfs with `sudo update-initramfs -u` and reboot.

Comment: Tried latest (46)  - also fail. Added listing

Comment: After the update it was still picking up version 41. Now it's loading it. Strange...